# Converting JSON object into C# list

Tags: javascript, c#, json

Before posting this question I tried other related posts but it didn't work out, so posting here.

I have got a Json stored in a hidden field that I am accessing in code behind file of my Mark-up page. I need to convert this Json into List and bind it to a grid, but while de-serializing it throws error saying `"Unexpected error encountered while parsing values &#39;&#39;"`.

Script for getting data from grid and making a Json object.

```
function BeforeSorting() {
    var list = UpdateDataSource();
    $("#SortingField").val(list);
}

function UpdateDataSource() {
    var list="";
    var grid = $find("DetailsGrid");
    var rows = grid.get_rows();
    for(var i =0 ; i<rows.get_length();i++){
        var name = rows.get_row(i).get_cellByColumnKey("Name").get_value();
        var country = rows.get_row(i).get_cellByColumnKey("Country").get_value();
        var gender = rows.get_row(i).get_cellByColumnKey("Gender").get_value();
        var age = rows.get_row(i).get_cellByColumnKey("Age").get_value();
        var uniqueKey = rows.get_row(i).get_cellByColumnKey("UniqueKey").get_value();

        list = list + '{"Name":"' + name + '", "Country":"' + country + '", "Gender":"' + gender + '", "Age":' + age + ', "UniqueKey":' + uniqueKey + '},';
    }
    list = "["+list.substr(0, list.length - 1)+"]";
    return JSON.parse(list);
}
```

The model class:

```
public class Details
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public int UniqueKey { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

The code for de-serializing the json and retrieving data as a list of the model class.

```
protected void DetailsGrid_ColumnSorted(object sender, Infragistics.Web.UI.GridControls.SortingEventArgs e)
{
    var dataSource = SortingField.Value;
    List<Details> result = (List<Details>)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(dataSource, typeof(List<Details>));
    DetailsGrid.DataSource = result;
    DetailsGrid.DataBind();
}
```

The json string as obtained:

```
"[{"Name":"Jerry", "Country":"U.S.A.", "Gender":"Male", "Age":20, "UniqueKey":1},{"Name":"Tom", "Country":"U.K", "Gender":"Male", "Age":10, "UniqueKey":2},{"Name":"George", "Country":"Gremany", "Gender":"Male", "Age":38, "UniqueKey":3},{"Name":"Kate", "Country":"France", "Gender":"Female", "Age":40, "UniqueKey":4},{"Name":"Jenny", "Country":"Poland", "Gender":"Female", "Age":25, "UniqueKey":5}]"
```

Comment: it seems you're setting the value to a javascript object, not a JSON string - in fact, you're creating a JSON string the hard way, then parsing it ... to pass JSON on to the server, you'd JSON.stringify a javascript object resulting in a JSON string

Comment: `The json string as obtained` is most likely `[object Object]`

Comment: I tried using JSON.stringify but then it is not able to parse the List into Json and throws error in the script itself... Can you give any other easy way to achieve above functionality?

Comment: read this [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) - hope that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create `list` as an array and add items as JavaScript objects and then convert it to JSON using `JSON.stringify`

```
function UpdateDataSource() {        
    var grid = $find("DetailsGrid");
    var rows = grid.get_rows();
    var list = [];
    for(var i =0 ; i < rows.get_length(); i++){
        var item = {
            Name : rows.get_row(i).get_cellByColumnKey("Name").get_value(),
            Country : rows.get_row(i).get_cellByColumnKey("Country").get_value(),
            Gender : rows.get_row(i).get_cellByColumnKey("Gender").get_value(),
            Age : rows.get_row(i).get_cellByColumnKey("Age").get_value(),
            UniqueKey : rows.get_row(i).get_cellByColumnKey("UniqueKey").get_value()
        };

        list.push(item);
    }
    return JSON.stringify(list);
}
```

The code for de-serializing the json and retrieving data as a list of the model class can be refactored to

```
protected void DetailsGrid_ColumnSorted(object sender, Infragistics.Web.UI.GridControls.SortingEventArgs e) {
    var dataSource = SortingField.Value;
    var result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Details>>(dataSource);
    DetailsGrid.DataSource = result;
    DetailsGrid.DataBind();
}
```

UPDATE as suggested by @Adnreas should produce the same result.

```
function UpdateDataSource() {        
    var grid = $find("DetailsGrid");
    var rows = grid.get_rows();
    var list = rows.map(function(row) {
        return {
            Name: row.get_cellByColumnKey("Name").get_value(),
            Country: row.get_cellByColumnKey("Country").get_value(),
            Gender: row.get_cellByColumnKey("Gender").get_value(),
            Age: row.get_cellByColumnKey("Age").get_value(),
            UniqueKey: row.get_cellByColumnKey("UniqueKey").get_value()
        };
    });
    return JSON.stringify(list);
}
```

Comment: Why not simplify this even more and use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map): [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xemmm9y9/)

Comment: Wow...thanks Nkosi... it worked.. A minor change in your code change = to : while making the JSON object .ie. Name : and not Name =

Comment: @zainul, Glad to help. Thanks for the update. Typo on my part. The suggestion by Andreas to simplify list is also very good. Happy Coding!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do

```
protected void DetailsGrid_ColumnSorted(object sender, Infragistics.Web.UI.GridControls.SortingEventArgs e)
{
    var dataSource = SortingField.Value;
    List<Details> result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Details>>(dataSource);
    DetailsGrid.DataSource = result;
    DetailsGrid.DataBind();
}
```